# Custom annotation with conditions

Tags: java, validation, annotations

I am creating a post-spring web service endpoint and taking an Object with around 7-8 String variables among other variables. While validation request, I need to test same conditions on each of them such as-

- Condition 1 it true continue else throw an exception.
- Condition 2 it true continue else throw exception.
- Condition 3 it true continue else throw exception

3-4 more business logic validation just like above and its a lot of if-else, 1 way is to create a method and pas these variables sequentially which doesn't make much of a difference. I was wondering if there is a way to write all these validations in some other java file and create a custom annotation like @CustomValidator which I can add on each variable and it will automatically test values based on validation logic written in other java file or throw the relevant exception.

- I cannot use hibernate validator.
- this definitely could be done by Hibernate validator or some other framework but I want to do it old school core java way.

Comment: Sounds like a perfect fit for [JSR-303](https://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/). In which [Hibernate Validator](http://hibernate.org/validator/) is the reference implementation. There's also [Apache BVal](http://bval.apache.org/) however.

Comment: @Jaims thanks for replying but as I said I cannot use hibernate and Apache BVal seems to be using it a lot which I can't use, plus it will solve basic NotNull, NotEmply and Size problem only. I still have to perform other validations.

Comment: @shrikant.sharma your "I cannot use bean validation" looks like an arbitrary restriction. It's the standard, battle-tested, right tool for the job. **Why** can't you use it? Why don't you do what's needed to simply remove that arbitrary restriction?

Comment: @JBNizet Because we have nexus repository and adding a new dependency in it would require lots of approval.

Comment: That's the most invalid reason I can imagine. If it takes more time to approve the usage of a standard, free, open-source, officially-supported, appropriate dependency than to re-develop an equivalent, then you should probably just find a new employer, or just be patient: they are the ones making the company lose time and money, not you. Their problem to fix, not yours.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Oval framework. OVal is a pragmatic and extensible validation framework for any kind of Java objects (not only JavaBeans).
http://oval.sourceforge.net/